# does Boost build the shared object by default?

Tags: c++, boost, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I encoutered an issue when build Boost-required project via cl.exe on Windows which is the compiler cannot find the `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_75.lib` and after searching i found this is a static library and i built the Boost by default which produces the shared library(at least i suppose to be, please point me if it isn't) `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_75.lib`(which does not contain the `-s` chars), hence i added the `\MD` option to cl.exe command and the produced executable works then.

However, when i deleted the `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_75.lib`, i supposed it won't work cause im using dynamic linking, but strangly it still works.

So, what's the gimmick in this situation, has the code been linked to the executable while the compile-time  and if so, isn't the `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_75.lib` file alredy a static library?

Comment: I believe `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-x64-1_75.lib` is an import library requiring a dll of a similar name at runtime. The `libboost_serialization-vc142-mt-s-x64-1_75.lib` would be a static library and not use a dll at runtime.

Comment: ***does Boost build the shared object by default?*** I think this depends on what options you use when compiling boost from source. I have done this 100s of times at work but I have had it scripted for more than a decade so I don't think about the options any more.

Comment: @drescherjm thx i recompiled the boost library by static library and turns out the previous one is much smaller and must be a import library